# how to index all files on a android device

Tags: java, android, search, indexing

i'm developing a app that index path of all files on device in a **sql database**

later i'm going to use that database for fast searching

so far i'm using [apache's common-io](https://commons.apache.org/io/) library to get all Files and Directories within sd-card

```
Collection<File> sdCardFiles = org.apache.commons.io.FileUtils.listFilesAndDirs(new File(sdCard),
 new RegexFileFilter(".*"),
 TrueFileFilter.TRUE);
```

then insert them into database

```
List<String> temp = new ArrayList<>();
for (File file : sdCardFiles) {
    temp.add(file.getPath());
    if (temp.size() > 10) {
        db.insertBunch(temp);
        temp.clear();
        }
    }
}
```

1.is there another way to do this in order to use less Cpu , Ram and Time?

2.most of files have same parent Directory so can we use something like a Trie for this case?

3.how to do this via `MediaStore`?

i tested this code on a Samsung J7 prime it consume 15mb Ram and 5% cpu (at highest level) to index about 40,000 files

Comment: "i'm developing a app that index path of all files on device in a sql database" -- there already is a database of all files on the device, called `MediaStore`. It exists on every Android device. Why are you building another one?

Comment: oops i didn't know that ._. thanks a lot @CommonsWare